# Взаимодействие функций

Tags: javascript

```
     let test = (o) => {
        console.log(o);
 }
    
    function LeftMainNav(){
        let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    }
```

как можно из  test изменить значение setOpen на true?

Comment: а кто такой `useState` и что он делает и возвращает?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, react очевидно

Comment: так и вызвать `setOpen(true)`

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, но test не знает что такое setOpen

Comment: Ответ - никак. Переменная `open` и функция `setOpen()` существуют только в момент работы функции `LeftMainNav` и взаимодействовать с ними извне нельзя

Comment: Однако с ними можно работать изнутри, опираясь на значения извне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мы имеем дело с Реакт, можно сделать так:  в `<LeftMainNav/>` рендерим компонент `<Test/>` в `props` которого передаём `setOpen`.  Далее в компоненте `<Test/>` вызываем `setOpen` в функции `test` которая вызывается при нажатии кнопки.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function LeftMainNav() {
  let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>LeftMainNav</h4>
      <h3>Open is: {open.toString()}</h3>
      <Test setOpen={setOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default LeftMainNav;

const Test = ({ setOpen }) => {
  let test = (o) => {
    setOpen(true);
    console.log(o);
  };
  return <button onClick={test}>Run test function</button>;
};
```

Чтобы `open` менялся с `false` на `true` и обратно можно написать так:

```
let test = (o) => {
  setOpen((open) => !open);
  console.log(o);
};
```